# Vertically centering an uploaded image preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filereader

I'm displaying a user-uploaded image preview on my site, but I want to be able to vertically center it within a div.  I have attempted to do this by setting the image's `margin-top` using Javascript once it's finished uploading as follows (where `$img` is the image in question):

```
reader.onloadend = (function() {
    var $parentDiv = $img.parent();
    $img.css('margin-top', ($parentDiv.height() - $img.height()) / 2);
});
```

The [FileReader documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileReader) I've read leads me to believe that `onloadend` will be called once the file upload has completed, and that seems to be the case.  Regardless of the size of the image, however, `$img.height()` is returning `0` at the time `onloadend` is called.

It seems that this is due to the fact that the value simply isn't available yet.  If I upload a second image (clearing the existing image preview), then re-upload the first image, the function works; `$img.height()` returns the correct value. Calling it via the console afterwards returns correctly as well.

Is there an accepted way of handling this? Is there any way to know when the value of `.height()` will be usable other than calling it at intervals until it is greater than zero?  Thanks!

Comment: Why not handle the vertical centering with CSS? You're using HTML5 stuff, so you clearly have no desire to support old browsers, so you should just be able to add `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;` to the parent `div`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to work around the zero-height issue with a variation on Michał Czernow's 'ghost element' CSS vertical-centering technique ([CSS Tricks: Centering in the Unknown](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/)). This would require no javascript manipulation of the image.

Use CSS to add a pseudo-element to your container div:

```
.container:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: -0.25em; /* Adjusts for spacing */
}
```

That 'ghost' element essentially becomes a scaffold for your image, style the image with `vertical-align: middle;` and whenever you update the image it should just work.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joemaller/sWCve/) showing how this might work.

Comment: Make sure that the image has a `width` defined. e.g. `width: 100%` or for me `width: calc(100% - 1px)`.